# Proof that with $b < 0$, $a$ mod $b \in (b,0]$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I was trying to prove that $a$ mod $b \in (b,0]$ when $b < 0$.
To do that basically I need to prove that $a - b\lfloor a/b \rfloor < 0$ which means that we need to prove that $b\lfloor a / b\rfloor > a$.
The only way I found to do that is to show that the absolute value of $\lfloor a / b \rfloor > a / b$ weh b < 0. But I don't think is a consistent proof.
How should I do?

Comment: Uhm what's your definition for $a \mod b$?

Comment: Note:  $\lfloor a/b \rfloor \le a/b$; multiply both sides by $b$ (and don't forget to reverse the inequality when $b<0$)

Comment: Oh I missed to reverse the inequality, now is all clear

Answer (score 1):

We have $\lfloor a/b\rfloor\le a/b$.

Because we're saying $b<0$, when multiplying both sides by $b$ the inequality must be reversed:

$b\lfloor a/b\rfloor \color{red}\ge a$.

Hence $a-b\lfloor a/b\rfloor\le0$.